# What does Elasticsearch automatic slicing do?

Tags: elasticsearch

What does [Elasticsearch automatic slicing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#docs-reindex-automatic-slice) do? I find the documentation to be very laconic about this function. I tried searching for other explanations of this functionality, but to no avail. Neither I have managed to find what slice is in Elasticsearch.

Comment: The most comprehensive source of information is the Github issues and pull requests: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/20624 + https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/20767

Comment: Reading through the issues, they describe mostly implementation details and not what would help to understand the implemented functionality.

Comment: Have you read the related link about [sliced scrolls](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html#sliced-scroll)?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't seem to explain what a slice is. Not knowing what a slice is in Elasticsearch might be my fundamental problem.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Automatic slicing is a way to parallelize work for a few different endpoints, such as [reindex](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#docs-reindex-automatic-slice), [update by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html#docs-update-by-query-automatic-slice) and [delete by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html#docs-delete-by-query-automatic-slice).

The three above APIs all work the same way by making a [scroll query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html) over the target index. Scroll queries provide a more performant way of making queries yielding big result sets than normal paged queries. Scroll queries can be further improved by [slicing them](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html#sliced-scroll).

In clear, if a query is supposed to return a big amount of hits, you can make a normal query and page through results using `from`/`size`, but that will not be performant because of [deep-paging](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/pagination.html). To circumvent that issue, ES allows you to use scroll queries in order to get results in batches of N hits. Those scroll queries can further be improved by slicing them, i.e. split the scroll in multiple slices which can be consumed independently by your client application.

So, say you have a query which is supposed to return 1,000,000 hits, and you want to scroll over that result set in batches of 50,000 hits, using a normal scroll query (i.e. without slicing), your client application will have to make the first scroll call and then 20 more synchronous calls (i.e. one after another) to retrieve each batch of 50K hits.

By using slicing, you can parallelize the 20 scroll calls. If your client application is multi-threaded, you can make each scroll call use 5 (e.g.) slices, and thus, you'll end up with 5 slices of ~10K hits that can be consumed by 5 different threads in your application, instead of having a single thread consume 50K hits. You can thus leverage the full computing power of your client application to consume those hits.

The ideal number of slices should be a multiple of the number of shards in the source index. For the best performance, you should pick the same number of slices as there are shards in your source index. For that reason, you might want to use automatic slicing instead of manual slicing, as ES will pick that number for you.

Comment: Ah, so slices are just a transient performance optimization, correct? My first impression from the documentation was that slices are a way for persistent partitioning of data.

Comment: Absolutely, the persistent partitioning of the data is already taken care of by the sharding infrastructure. Slicing is simply a transient optimization that lasts the time it takes to run the queries.

Comment: Great, anything else you need?

Comment: Thanks! It's clear now. The main thing that helped me is that slices are not persistent, but instead an internal optimization to allow parallelization.

Comment: Hey do you know how Spark parallelism affects this? I was running a job with 8000 partition and got this error ```The number of slices [2666] is too large. It must be less than [1024]```